# Can't append reducer state in redux toolkit

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to append the state.data with action.payload and i have tried everything it gives unidefined on .concat, .push or spreading in an array.

```
import { createAction, createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    const initialState = {};
    const request = createAction("allDataRequest");
    const success = createAction("allDataSuccess");
    const fail = createAction("allDataFailure");
    const clear = createAction("clearErrors");
    
    export const allServicesReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
      builder
        .addCase(request, (state, action) => {
          state.loading = true;
        })
        .addCase(success, (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.data = action.payload;
          // I want to append this state.data with payload
          //state.data = state.data.concat(action.payload)
          //state.data = [...state.data, ...action.payload]
          // However i get stae.data undefined on both
        })
        .addCase(fail, (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = action.payload;
        })
        .addCase(clear, (state, action) => {
          state.error = null;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because **your initial state does *not* have a `.data` field**:

```
 const initialState = {};
```

So, yes, it's going to be empty to begin with.

You need to either provide `const initialState = {data: []}` so there *is* a field, or update the reducer logic to handle the case where it doesn't exist.